Style matter-js bodies
I Want To Create This Ping Effect.
You can see more about it on https://stake.com/casino/games/plinko

I'm re-building this plinko game and want to create this effect of a 'ping'. I got to a point where I can fire up events on body collision of the ball and pin. My question is, since the matter-js renderer is limited to simple games and debugging. How can I style the pins to emit this ping effect ?
  // if (bodyB.label.includes("ball") && bodyA.label.includes("pin")) {
  //   console.log("Ball hit pin");
  //   // Style pin to create a wave effect when hit
  //   bodyA.render.fillStyle = "red";

  // }


Please share a [mcve]. Probably, you'll want to use a custom renderer.

I see you've tagged this pixi.js. Are you using pixi as the renderer?

I was hoping to use pixi or like p5.js or any other renderer library along side matter-js, thank you for the link provided. I like the react example; The interesting part is you made the JSX divs part of the canvas ?

The React example in this link uses plain HTML DOM, there's no canvas. Using any other library is too broad--please pick something and write some code and build the skeleton leading up to the "ping" effect, and when you're stuck, then you can ask a specific question about how to fix your issue.

"fire up events on body collision"
You can look on my test
https://mlich.zam.slu.cz/js-matter/js-sorter/mechanical-sorter.htm
https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Body.html#property_collisionFilter
You can define collision by group or (mask and category)

Body.collisionFilter.category - what i am (0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x20 or 0b00000001, 0b00000010, 0b00000100 ...)
Body.collisionFilter.mask - collide with (cat1 or cat2 or cat3 = 0b001 or 0b010 or 0b100 = mask 0b111)
Body.collisionFilter.group - all in group non collide, if you have 5 ball, any ball must collide with any, you must use 5 differend group
new_group = Body.nextGroup(true);
You can use event for define collision callback
https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Events.html



var Events = Matter.Events,


Events.on(engine, 'collisionStart', function(event) {
        var pairs = event.pairs, // colide pair bodyA with bodyB
            i_end = pairs.length; // faster for cycle
        for (var i = 0; i < i_end; i++) {
var a = pair.bodyA
var b = pair.bodyB
// you must identify ball by compare with category
if (a.collisionFilter.category==myCat.ball)
            {...}
        } else { if (b.collisionFilter.category==myCat.ball)
            {...}
...
}
Events.on(engine, 'collisionActive', function(event) {...}
Events.on(engine, 'collisionEnd', function(event) {...}



"style the pins" - Look on render
https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Body.html#property_render
If you use matter example, you must active color mode.


    var render = Render.create({
        element: $('#screen_simulation'), //document.body,
        engine: engine,
        options: {
            width: screen.data.size.w,
            height: screen.data.size.h,
            background: 'transparent'
//          ,wireframes: false  // color mode or wireframe mode
//          ,showAngleIndicator: true
            ,showCollisions: true
           }
       });



